# Netty 4 Bytebuffer WritableBytes clarification

Tags: netty

I'm trying to understand ByteBuffer. Below is the program.

```
        ByteBuf heapBuff = Unpooled.buffer(18);
        System.out.println("writableBytes " + heapBuff.writableBytes());
        heapBuff.writeCharSequence("RAJKUMAR NATARAJAN TESTE", Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println("readableBytes " + heapBuff.readableBytes());
        System.out.println("writableBytes " + heapBuff.writableBytes());
```

output of the above program is

```
        writableBytes 18
        readableBytes 24
        writableBytes 104
```

What is the logic of calculation of writableBytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer writing will check if their are enough writable bytes to fit the data and if not will increase the size of the buffer under the hood. This is what is called when checking if enough writable bytes and is why the capacity increases. If you add 24 to 104 = 128 which is a power of two.

AbstractByteBuf.class

```
final void ensureWritable0(int minWritableBytes) {
    ensureAccessible();
    if (minWritableBytes <= writableBytes()) {
        return;
    }

    if (minWritableBytes > maxCapacity - writerIndex) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format(
                "writerIndex(%d) + minWritableBytes(%d) exceeds maxCapacity(%d): %s",
                writerIndex, minWritableBytes, maxCapacity, this));
    }

    // Normalize the current capacity to the power of 2.
    int newCapacity = alloc().calculateNewCapacity(writerIndex + minWritableBytes, maxCapacity);

    // Adjust to the new capacity.
    capacity(newCapacity);
}
```

Resources:

[ByteBuf JavaDoc](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html)

[AbstractByteBuf.class (github)](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/buffer/AbstractByteBuf.java)